# Getting Heroku to precompile assets to Amazon aws s3

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, sinatra, assets, rake-task

Almost there with my issue of getting AWS S3 to serve my heroku app its static assets

Everything works locally, i run my rake task and then the assets get precompiled to AWS ( though there is never any output in the terminal?)

Then to heroku, where i set my ENV variables like so

```
heroku config:add  aws_access_key=mysecretkey aws_secret_key=mypublickey aws_bucket=mybucketname
```

I have two buckets, one for dev and one for production. Do i need to set anything else in the heroku:config?

Heres what i have so far

config.rb

```
AssetSync.configure do |con|
con.fog_provider = 'AWS'
con.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
con.fog_directory = ENV['aws_bucket']
con.aws_access_key_id = ENV['aws_access_key']
con.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['aws_secret_key']
con.prefix = "assets"
con.public_path = Pathname("./public")
end
```

Question here, how much of this will heroku read and use, I know i have to set the ENV explicitly in heroku but will it read the rest and carry out the rest of the task, ie will it read prefix, public_path etc ?

Rakefile

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require './config/env' if File.exists?('config/env.rb')
require './config/config'

namespace :assets do
desc "Precompile assets"
task :precompile do
 AssetSync.sync
end
```

end

When running

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

i get the output

```
`rake assets:precompile` attached to terminal...up, run.2942 The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure. Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org  (in /app)
```

Then it just returns to the terminal, I expected a list of all the assets that where to be compiled listed as the task was being carried out. Upon checking my bucket in aws, it is empty

EDIT

Output after heroku logs --tail

```
 2013-03-19T10:55:50+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` by richlewis14@gmail.com
 2013-03-19T10:55:52+00:00 heroku[run.6701]: State changed from starting to up
 2013-03-19T10:55:53+00:00 heroku[run.6701]: Awaiting client
 2013-03-19T10:55:53+00:00 heroku[run.6701]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
 2013-03-19T10:55:59+00:00 heroku[run.6701]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
 2013-03-19T10:56:00+00:00 heroku[run.6701]: Process exited with status 0
 2013-03-19T10:56:00+00:00 heroku[run.6701]: State changed from up to complete
```

More was added after about 15 minutes

```
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

 Error:       An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
(Errno::ECONNRESET)

  Command:     heroku logs --tail
  Version:     heroku-gem/2.35.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bundler error due to the source stated in the Gemfile. It is not related to the asset compilation per se.

Specify

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

at the top of your Gemfile.

Comment: any more errors? heroku is a little quiet about those errors. you could try to simulate your asset compilation locally. create a gemset or something else and try to do the task. i recently had the problems heroku not compiling assets because i had some custom rake tasks which couldnt be loaded on heroku due to missing gems

Comment: not that i can see, asset compilation works locally, its getting them compiled for heroku that is the issue

Comment: Try opening two terminals, go to your project dir in both and run 'heroku logs --tail' in one of them and 'heroku run rake assets:precompile' in the other. Post the output of the log, please.

Comment: @MoMolog and anyone else - why compile the assets when in production, why not compile them locally and push to the AWS bucket? I've not used it myself, so I'm just wondering.

Comment: update, i have just ran heroku run rake assets:precompile I changed the bucket name to the same one in both environments, previously locally it was say applecatering and via heroku config:add i set it to applecateringprod, so both set as applecatering for now. so now i checked the bucket and sure enough there are my assets.. So did i make a big error and have two bucketnames? the question now is how can i tell if my assets are actually being served from AWS?